# InputMethodService onCreateInputView never called

Tags: android, android-input-method

I have a very simple InputMethodService where all I do is log the different stages of the lifecycle. My `onCreateInputView` is never called, and the log shows strange things.

```
  MyInput       D  onCreate
                D  onInitializeInterface
                D  onBindInput
                D  onStartInput
                D  onUnbindInput
                D  onBindInput
                D  onStartInput
                D  onUnbindInput
                D  onBindInput
                D  onStartInput
                D  onShowInputRequested
```

I only clicked on a text input when the `onShowInputRequested` is called. When a navigate between screens, it cycles between `onBind`, `onStartInput`, `onUnbind`. Am I missing something?

```
public class MyInput extends InputMethodService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyInput";

    private InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeInterface() {
        super.onInitializeInterface();
        Log.d(TAG, "onInitializeInterface");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateInputView");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_keyboard, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInput() {
        super.onFinishInput();
        Log.d(TAG, "onFinishInput");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartInput");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInputView(boolean finishingInput) {
        super.onFinishInputView(finishingInput);
        Log.d(TAG, "onFinishInputView");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onShowInputRequested(int flags, boolean configChange) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onShowInputRequested");
        return super.onShowInputRequested(flags, configChange);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindInput() {
        super.onBindInput();
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindInput");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnbindInput() {
        super.onUnbindInput();
        Log.d(TAG, "onUnbindInput");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartInputView restarting = " + restarting);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCurrentInputMethodSubtypeChanged(InputMethodSubtype subtype) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCurrentInputMethodSubtypeChanged");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change [onShowInputRequested](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onShowInputRequested(int,%20boolean)):

```
@Override
public boolean onShowInputRequested(int flags, boolean configChange) {
    return true;
}
```

I had generally the same, that in some cases my keyboard was not showing, and this helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I've removed all the overriden method and left only the `onCreateInputView` and it is now called, no idea what wasn't working, especially because I was calling the superclass methods everywhere...